# Find the browser version using css

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with IE8, so I need to apply some css only if browser is not IE8

In html I can do it using

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But I want to filter this using CSS

Is there a way where I can instruct browser **apply these styles if its not 
IE8** ?

For example, how can i make this css not have any impact in IE8?

```
@font-face{
//some css
}
```

Comment: Using IE conditional comments, apply a class to your body and target that class in CSS.

Comment: Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem   Ask instead question regarding: `I have a problem with IE8` Which problem???

Answer (score 2):

Conditional comments would work `(<!--[if lte IE 8]><stylesheet><![endif]-->)`, but if you want to do it all in the stylesheet, there [is a way:](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)

```
body {  
    color: red; /* all browsers, of course */  
    color: green\9; /* IE only */  
}
```

The important thing here is the "\9", which has to be exactly "\9". I'm not clear on exactly why this is.

EDIT: The \9 hack isn't enough by itself. To exclude IE9, you also need the [`:root` hack:](http://blog.vervestudios.co/blog/post/2011/05/13/IE9-Only-CSS-Hack.aspx)

```
:root body {
    color: red\9; /* IE9 only */  
}
```

Other browsers besides IE might support :root, so combine it with the \9 hack if you're using it to target IE9.

**IE6**

Lastly, we have the underscore hack, which most designers are familiar with by now. Rather than the * symbol, we use the underscore. This will target only Internet Explorer 6.

```
body {
 color: red; /* all browsers, of course */
 color : green\9; /* IE8 and below */
 *color : yellow; /* IE7 and below */
 _color : orange; /* IE6 */
}
```

**For More Information**

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters--net-10575

Comment: thanks Bhavin +1 for the answer
is there a way to target IE8 only just like how you have done for IE only?

Comment: @vignesh The final example above targets IE8 so you just need to remove IE6 and set IE7 and below to the same as "all browsers".

Comment: any selector for all browsers except IE8?

Answer (score 1):

[IE 8 doesn't support media queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) - you can use that (just insert your CSS inside some broad media query).

Have a look at list of [browser-specific CSS hacks here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/) or [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie7-ie8-css-hacks/).
Below I copy-pasted some concerning IE 8:

```
/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For only IE of specific version best way is to use conditional comments in HTML, like this (and like you mentioned):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

But also you can do in this way for IE 8 only:

```
@media \0screen {
    body { background: blue; }
}
```

More info here : http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/

Comment: is there a reverse for IE8 only? I need something that should not be applied only for IE8

Comment: As far as I know - not, so you need to use combination, something like this:
IE 6 and 7
`@media screen\9 {
    body { background: red; }
}`
IE 9 and 10
`@media screen and (min-width:0{{ content }}) {
    body { background: yellow; }
}`